# Typescript + React + D3v4: `Object is possibly 'undefined' error`, at d3 scaleBand

Tags: typescript, d3.js

How to resolve the `Object is possibly 'undefined' error`, that occurs at **'yScale'**

```
interface IData {
  id: string;
  phone_number: string,
}
const data : IData[]
const devices = data.map((d) => d.phone_number)
const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, 30 * devices.length])
  .domain(devices)

const yAccessor = (d: string) => yScale(d)
```

I think it is occurring because typescript thinks d3's scaleBand will return undefined because 'devices' variable is any empty array. When i hover over 'devices' in my IDE, it says `'let devices: string[]'`. However, 'devices' in its initial state is empty (because a search has not been submitted). This error would not occur if 'devices' already contains a list of elements.

Here is d3-scale's [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/index.d.ts)

```
export interface ScaleBand<Domain extends { toString(): string }> {
    /**
     * Given a value in the input domain, returns the start of the corresponding band derived from the output range.
     * If the given value is not in the scale’s domain, returns undefined.
     *
     * @param x  A value from the domain.
     */
    (x: Domain): number | undefined;
...
}
```

Comment: `const data = IData[]`.. This isn't right. Do you mean `let data: IData[];`? Or `const data: IDate[] = [....]`? In addition, may I know when exactly is this being called? Is it part of the useEffect hook or something?

Comment: yeah.. i have corrected it. actually im using a useContext hook to pass data to the component

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to allow undefined/null values in the typescript compiler settings like in tsconfig. However I'm not sure whether that is recommended or not.

Comment: shouldn't the alternatvie be a function since d3.scaleBand is a function? i

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `data` could be an empty array,  you could do a check before `yScale` is called to ensure that `data` is not empty.

```
if (!data.length) {
  return;
}
const devices = data.map((d) => d.phone_number)
const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, 30 * devices.length])
  .domain(devices)
```

This will cause an early return within your hook/method if data is an empty array.

Comment: yeah i realized one possible way was to check if data is empty and use a tenary operator with the else condition being to fallback to an empty function () => {}, to clear the error, but then it not really the best method because it causes typescript errors when doing things like:  yScale.bandwith() or yScale(d) + buffer